# How can I make Gherkin scenarios for automated scalability test?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, scalability, gherkin

I am trying to automatize scalability tests of our tool. Since I need to try lots of input values to see the tool's limits, this kind of a work costs a lot for my case because I need to do a few steps with the hardware before changing the input value. This prevents the automated scalability tests. So how can I make scalability tests automated in my tool? What would be best approach? We are using Gherkin scenarios. I thought to write a script which generates automatic gherkin scenarios itself. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use SpecFlow, you are on c#, for running a set of generated Gherkin files it sounds to me like you are using the wrong tool for your problem.

Tools like SpecFlow and Cucumber both use Gherkin. The strength of Gherkin is that it is human readable and allow better communication than reading and discussing code. Your non-technical co-workers can read and understand Gherkin. They can probably not read c# code and understand what the expected behaviour of your system should be.

You want to generate a lot of combinations that should be executed. In that situation, I would use any unit testing framework and use that for running a lot of different tests implemented in c#. A programming language is designed for that kind of work. Gherkin is not designed for that kind of work.

You may be interested in this [blog post](https://cucumber.io/blog/2014/03/03/the-worlds-most-misunderstood-collaboration-tool) where Aslak Hellesøy talks about Cucumber as a misunderstood tool. Replace Cucumber in the text with SpecFlow and you will see that it still applies.